# An input that changes its value to min or max value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I want a number field that limits its range so when you set a value least than min value it turns min value and when you put a value grater than max value it changes to max value.

I tried it with debounce but it makes a transition for every digit. If I could ignore onChange events except the last one, it would be correct.

This is my component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

const MinMaxField = ({ name, value, error, onChange, min, max, placeholder }) => {
    const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(value)

    const correctInput = debounce(inputValue => {
        const validValue = inputValue < min ? min : inputValue > max ? max : inputValue
        setInternalValue(validValue)
        onChange(validValue)
    }, 1200)


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;
        setInternalValue(inputValue)
        correctInput(inputValue)
    }

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <input
                className={`form-control ${error ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
                type={'number'}
                name={name}
                value={internalValue}
                placeholder={placeholder || ''}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {error && <span className="invalid-feedback">{error[0]}</span>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MinMaxField;
```

So is there any kind of library or method to make it work correctly?